# Submeter formulario ao carregar a pagina

Tags: jquery, formulário

Eu tenho um formulário e queria que ao ser carregado a página, esse formulário fosse submetido.
Estou usando o código abaixo, porém ele fica em um loop infinito.

```
<form name="teste" action="inicial" method="post">
Nome do Usuário: <input type="text" name="user">
<input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    window.onload = function() {    
    document.forms[0].submit();
    }
});
```

Quando carrego a página, fica submetendo infinitamente.
Pensei que executaria apenas uma vez.

Comment: tenta tirar o window.onload = function() { } e pegar o form com um seletor $('form').submit();

Comment: Se o a requisição está indo para a própria página, vai dar um loop infinito, pois ela vai submeter pra ela mesma, e quando carregar vai faze-lo de novo. assim eternamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode ser que seu formulário esteja redirecionando após ser enviado para o mesmo link onde ele está, aí ele vai submeter de novo.

Aproveitando essa forma de escrever me parece mais limpa e simples.

```
$(function(){ //Código escrito de outra forma
  $("[name='teste']").submit();
})
```